# How to find the Java class using System.out.println?

Tags: java, logging, websphere, system.out

Logs are being redirected as SystemOut. How to find the Java class printing these statements?

> [7/11/19 10:34:41:786 EDT] 0000010b **SystemOut**     O [2019-07-11
>   10:34:41,785] [WebContainer : 2] **DEBUG** loader.Loader (getRow:1533)-
>   Result row:

I want to block/suppress/remove these SystemOut statements.

---

UPDATE added stack traces of caller of PrintStream based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57065205/2891264) by dbourne.

```
21:02:00.444 0x30004f00              mt.0        > java/io/PrintStream.println(Ljava/lang/String;)V bytecode method, this = 0x7ffa75098
21:02:00.444 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.0        - jstacktrace:
21:02:00.444 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [1] java.io.PrintStream.println (PrintStream.java:829)
21:02:00.444 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [2] com.ibm.ejs.ras.hpel.HpelHelper.printHeader (HpelHelper.java:662)
21:02:00.444 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [3] com.ibm.ejs.ras.RasHelper.printHeader (RasHelper.java:1898)
21:02:00.444 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [4] com.ibm.ejs.ras.RasHelper.printHeader (RasHelper.java:1892)
21:02:00.444 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [5] com.ibm.ejs.ras.SystemOutStream.replaceSystemOutStream (SystemOutStream.java:156)
21:02:00.444 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [6] com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.redirectStream (WsServerImpl.java:459)
21:02:00.444 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [7] com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootLoggingServices (WsServerImpl.java:402)
21:02:00.444 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [8] com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start (WsServerImpl.java:201)
21:02:00.444 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [9] com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main (WsServerImpl.java:697)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [10] com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main (WsServer.java:59)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [11] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [12] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [13] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) (Compiled Code)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [14] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:508) (Compiled Code)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [15] com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain (WSLauncher.java:234)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [16] com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main (WSLauncher.java:101)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [17] com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run (WSLauncher.java:82)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [18] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [19] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [20] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) (Compiled Code)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [21] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:508) (Compiled Code)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [22] org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException (EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [23] org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run (EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [24] org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication (EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [25] org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start (EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [26] org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run (EclipseStarter.java:354)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [27] org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run (EclipseStarter.java:181)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [28] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [29] sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [30] sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [31] java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:508)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [32] org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework (Main.java:340)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [33] org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun (Main.java:282)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [34] org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run (Main.java:981)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [35] com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse (WSPreLauncher.java:413)
21:02:00.445 0x30004f00       j9trc_aux.1        - [36] com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main (WSPreLauncher.java:174)
21:02:00.446 0x30004f00              mt.6        < java/io/PrintStream.println(Ljava/lang/String;)V bytecode method
.
.
.
02:09:27.893 0x33dd3000              mt.1        > java/io/PrintStream.println(Ljava/lang/String;)V compiled method, this = 0x700d16a70
02:09:27.893 0x33dd3000       j9trc_aux.0        - jstacktrace:
02:09:27.893 0x33dd3000       j9trc_aux.1        - [1] java.io.PrintStream.println (PrintStream.java:829) (Compiled Code)
02:09:27.893 0x33dd3000       j9trc_aux.1        - [2] com.ibm.ejs.ras.SystemStream.writeWebSphereEvent (SystemStream.java:738) (Compiled Code)
02:09:27.893 0x33dd3000       j9trc_aux.1        - [3] com.ibm.ejs.ras.SystemOutStream.logMessage (SystemOutStream.java:330) (Compiled Code)
02:09:27.894 0x33dd3000       j9trc_aux.1        - [4] com.ibm.ejs.ras.SystemOutStream.processEvent (SystemOutStream.java:319) (Compiled Code)
02:09:27.894 0x33dd3000       j9trc_aux.1        - [5] com.ibm.ws.logging.WsHandlerWrapper.publish (WsHandlerWrapper.java:43)
02:09:27.894 0x33dd3000       j9trc_aux.1        - [6] java.util.logging.Logger.log (Logger.java:749) (Compiled Code)
02:09:27.894 0x33dd3000       j9trc_aux.1        - [7] com.ibm.ws.logging.WsLogger.deliverOrBuffer (WsLogger.java:416)
02:09:27.894 0x33dd3000       j9trc_aux.1        - [8] com.ibm.ws.logging.WsLogger.log (WsLogger.java:394)
02:09:27.894 0x33dd3000       j9trc_aux.1        - [9] com.ibm.ws.logging.WsLogger.logp (WsLogger.java:599) (Compiled Code)
02:09:27.894 0x33dd3000       j9trc_aux.1        - [10] org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger.log (Jdk14Logger.java:126)
02:09:27.894 0x33dd3000       j9trc_aux.1        - [11] org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger.info (Jdk14Logger.java:193)
02:09:27.894 0x33dd3000       j9trc_aux.1        - [12] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource (AbstractApplicationContext.java:473)
02:09:27.894 0x33dd3000       j9trc_aux.1        - [13] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
02:09:27.894 0x33dd3000       j9trc_aux.1        - [14] org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init> (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:92)
02:09:27.894 0x33dd3000       j9trc_aux.1        - [15] org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init> (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:77)
.
.
.
```

Comment: As we discussed on ServerFault, this is almost certainly coming from Hibernate logging statements, not `System.out.println` in any custom code.

Comment: for anyone reading, the ServerFault discussion is at https://serverfault.com/questions/974852/log-statements-are-logged-as-systemout-in-websphere-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IBM JDK provides a tracing facility that you can use to find who is calling any method.  To find who is calling System.out.println, add the following to your genericJvmArguments and restart the server.  The output, which will show a stack trace of the caller, should appear in your native_stdout.log file.

```
-Xtrace:print=mt,trigger=method{java/io/PrintStream.println,jstacktrace}
```

A snippet of the stack trace for a sample application, which calls System.out.println(), with the above JVM argument set, which identifies that the Hello.printHello (Hello.java:15) writes to System.out.

```
03:41:01.245*0x3277900 mt.0 > java/io/PrintStream.println(Ljava/lang/String;)V Bytecode method, This = 7fffff49f98
03:41:01.247 0x3277900 j9trc_aux.0 - jstacktrace:
03:41:01.248 0x3277900 j9trc_aux.1 - [1] java.io.PrintStream.println (PrintStream.java:829)
03:41:01.248 0x3277900 j9trc_aux.1 - [2] com.ibm.jvm.io.ConsolePrintStream.println (ConsolePrintStream.java:311)
03:41:01.250 0x3277900 j9trc_aux.1 - [3] Hello.printHello (Hello.java:15)
03:41:01.251 0x3277900 j9trc_aux.1 - [4] Hello.main (Hello.java:9)Hello World
03:41:01.253 0x3277900 mt.6 < java/io/PrintStream.println(Ljava/lang/String;)V Bytecode method
```

Comment: Thanks. Will get back once i get the opportunity to test this.

Comment: I have added two stack traces to the question. First has a redirection and the second has WsHandlerWrapper using SystemOutStream.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source code, I would suggest something like `grep "System.out"` over the whole source tree.

Another approach could be to write an implementation of `PrintStream` that dumps a stack trace to the console each time it is called. Then write a wrapper class that sets an instance of that new `PrintStream` for `out` (`System.setOut( new MyPrintStream( System.out ) )`) before it calls `main()` of your program's main class.

You can implement `MyPrintStream` in a way that it will only print a caller once, and only the line that holds the `out.print*()` statement. But however, you have to make sure that the program will execute all branches to be sure that all locations will be printed.